# How do I change my password on TV Tropes?

Tags: password-recovery

TV Tropes has an extremely odd form of login, and there seems to be no way to recover a lost password or to change an existing password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be reset at http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/password_reset.php .  I don't know if this is new, or the thread is just a manual alternative.

Comment: Ah, it looks like they've created a new account type which includes e-mail addresses. So all I need to do is to reset the password on my old account, log in, upgrade it to a version with an e-mail address, and then reset it again. Or something.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from [this](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/posts.php?discussion=5ld7gdqsyx49ikjep2qpdqem&page=1) forum discussion of TV Tropes, only admins can do that. Just ask them to do it posting a request on that thread.